# Deploy MEAN.JS on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, meanjs

I tried to deploy MEAN.JS on Google Cloud Platform (also the KeystoneJS CMS), but it doesn't work. I use the command-line tool online.

In the order, i installed Node.js, MongoDB, bower and grunt, then I try to deploy MEAN.JS :

- Install Node.js :

  `sudo apt-get install curl
  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
  sudo apt-get install -y nodejs nodejs-legacy`
- Install MongoDB :

  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
  echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`
- Install bower et Grunt :

  `sudo npm install -g bower
  sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`
- Install MEAN.js :

  `sudo npm install -g generator-meanjs
  mkdir mean
  cd mean
  yo meanjs
  grunt`

Here is the result on the command-line board :

`Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
    53 files lint free.
    Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
    2 files lint free.
    Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
    Running "watch" task
    Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
    Waiting...
    [nodemon] v1.2.1
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
    [nodemon] watching: app/views//. gruntfile.js server.js config//.js app/*/*.j
    s
    [nodemon] starting node --debug server.js
    debugger listening on port 5858
     NODE_ENV is not defined! Using default development environment
    js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
    Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
    MEAN.JS application started on port 3000`

I can define the NODE_ENV variable (test, development, all...) but it's the same problem.

---

The problem is :
It should work but whan i try to access to my IP:port (in this case 146.148.113.68:3000) : "This webpage is not available".
Is it a problem with the VM, the packages, MEAN.JS ? I have the same problem with the KeystoneJS CMS.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you seen this? https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mean/click-to-deploy

Comment: See also Bitnami's [MEAN stack on Google Cloud Platform](https://bitnami.com/stack/mean/cloud/google) for an easy deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure ports to your machine are open for access? When you deploy an app on Compute Engine, you have to edit network settings to allow custom ports. There's easy checkmark options for allowing HTTP and HTTPs traffic, but for custom ports, you will have to add port in settings.

[This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en) might be helpful but you can always find these things in the Cloud Console.

Also, now [Google Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/?q=mean) also supports MEAN stack deployment with both MEAN.io and MEAN.js flavors which simplifies the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine Only thing to change is the firewall settings which is blocking your web application ,there is no problem with VM or KeystoneJS CMS. You Need to just change the firewall settings for incoming and Outing Traffic:

[image: Fire Wall Settings]

You need to specify the ip and port number , i have given access to all ports temporarily for testing purpose.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try other services to host your MEANJS Web Application.
Heroku    : https://www.heroku.com/
Nodejitsu : https://www.nodejitsu.com/

If it works in these platoforms,then the problem is not with your cloud.